mutliple .c files connected in one header file
I would like to ask if it is okay to connect multiple .c files with one header file for example peripheral.h which will include function prototypes from motor.c and antena.c?
If I try it it works I just want to know if it is not prohibited or against best practice.
   // peripheral.h
#ifndef PERIPHERAL_H
#define PERIPHERAL_H

// Function declarations from motor.c
void motorFunction();

// Function declarations from antena.c
void antenaFunction();

#endif // PERIPHERAL_H


// motor.c
#include "peripheral.h"

void motorFunction() {
    // Function implementation
}


// antena.c
#include "peripheral.h"

void antenaFunction() {
    // Function implementation
}


// main.c
#include "peripheral.h"

int main() {
    motorFunction();
    antenaFunction();
    return 0;
}


What do you mean by "connected"? Please [edit] your question and show a simple example code.

Like this one peripheral.h with function prototypes from motor.c and antena.c and main.c with functions from motor.c and antena.c through peripheral.h.

Forbidden? No. Best Practice? Not really... suppose you outsource your motor coding to another team and your team only does antena. You gotta change your peripheral.h then! Why not start with the standard way in the first place?

Yes, it's fine.  Where the source files each expose a small number of functions and it is plausible that the functions could all be used in a single program, a single header for several source files makes sense.  There does need to be some commonality between the functions, though.  One header per source file is often the best choice.

You could also make a header for each, motor.h and antena.h, then include those headers in a single peripheral.h. What is your goal in having a single header?

It should be used in one program and the number of function prototypes is small I dont wanna uncover all functions from motor.c and antena.c to the rest of the program just functions I need externally so I have created just one header file for the right one.

Make all the functions static except those which may be called by name.  Those that can be called by name should be declared in a header.

Yes, it is fine to use single header file to describe the interface of multiple compilation units.
Usually you would have a separate header for each compilation unit, but sometimes merging multiple headers which are part of the same subsystem can make things easier. There is no right answer for this; you have to use your best judgement.
This style is often used when making small compiled libraries. Source files would be compiled into one binary library, and then library would be distributed as 1 header file and 1 binary file.

Goals of organizing header files include:

Keep things simple for humans to understand and work with, to reduce human errors and to reduce engineering costs.
Avoid including things where they are not needed, to avoid unnecessary conflicts and to reduce compilation costs in large projects.

A typical model that is used for header files includes:

For each source file that is exporting things to be used by other source files, create one header file with the same name (but different extension) that declares all the exported things (and the things necessary for those declarations, such as prerequisite types, including inclusions of other headers that are necessary).

Your model differs from the above model. If some client source file uses motorFunction but not antennaFunction (note that this is the spelling of “antenna” in English, different from your source code), then including peripheral.h will get it a declaration it does not need. That does not serve the goals above. Whether it is “okay” is a subjective question. If the things it declares are tightly associated, so that a human working with them is likely to consider them as “one thing,” it may be fine. But if they are separate things and some clients may want one and not the other, it may be undesirable.
